# Hover text color for Navigation menu not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, html-lists

I'm working off a template.  The template hover works fine when I load it in dreamweaver in its original form I tried copying all the exact code and styles from the template and for some reason on my site the background only changes to black and the text doesn't change to white.

```
.menu li a:hover
```

is the rule that is supposed to change it, and definitely is controlling the hover background color. Please help!

http://gregorydesignbuild.net/

Answer (score 4):

It is because you're using cufon for your menu, the cufon text is rendered and therefore the color can't change with `:hover`, it's not text anymore.

**Edit:** Take a look at this: [How To Fix Hover Effects In Cufon](http://galinsimeonov.com/?p=74)

Comment: Thanks for that link.  I looked into it but I already had the line hover:true added to the cufon-replace.js.  The template that I use also had the text hover working with the same cufon font. I might just change it to a light gray to get around the font color since it seems too hard to fix.